# How to move React dialog to top of the body using Onclick

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dialog

I have a `share-dialog` which I want to move when a user will click over it. Here in my case I have a multiple dialog box which can populate and want it to move with `id` associated with this dialog.

I have tried with some solution here as well but getting some error on the process any help/suggestion what I am doing wrong.

//dialog

```
<div className="share-request-dialog"  onClick={this.onClick(participant.id)}>
    <div className="alert-dialog-container">
        <---- dialog body --->
    </div>
</div>
```

//So far tried with this onClick function with both `style.top` and others as well

```
  onClick = (partId, e) => {
    
    var divClass = '.share-request-dialog'+partId;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
    let Y = scrollY;
    debugger
    // partId[0].style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
    divClass.offset().top = Y + 'px';
    console.log("Div is clicked" + partId);
}
```

/Errors

```
TypeError: divClass.offset is not a function
```

//basic design (Screen can be open mutiple over each other so want to move each one on to top of the screen on click over it)

[image]

Comment: If I get you correctly you want to move selected div horizontally?

Comment: @SM1105922 yes.. So its basically on click it should move to top of the screen.

Comment: Can you post basic visual design if you have one.

Comment: @SM1105922 updated . please let me know if anything else you are expecting

Comment: Do you want user to type in the div..Once he/she click and the text to be placed on the top of the div

Comment: No . on click over this dialog box it should be moved to top...

Comment: >> basic design (Screen can be open mutiple over each other so want to move each one on click over it) 

Are you just trying to get it on top of all other dialogs or position it to the top of the page???

Comment: @Ramakay want that dialog to move top of the screen/page .

Comment: @Ramakay I have updated my screen design . You can see there are multiple screen over each other so on click ithat particular screen should move to top. Any help would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

*Updated Answer*

I notice your code is written in React, you need to look into simply toggling the CSS class to one which has left and top 0 that is positioned absolutely.

OR you can simply set the div style top to zero like below - Non React code

If you want the dialog to *float* on top of others - simply use a `z-index:<high value>` to ensure they are the topmost from a stacking order.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <style>
      .share-request-dialog {
        background: blue;
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 25px;
        top: 300px;
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <script>
      const getOffset = (partId) => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-globals
        // partId[0].style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
        event.target.style.top = 0 + "px";
        console.log("Div is clicked" + partId);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="share-request-dialog" onClick="javascript:getOffset(5)">
      <div class="alert-dialog-container">
        <---- dialog body ---> ss
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-agnesi-rybp4?file=/index.html

Comment: Tried with yours 2nd one  here its coming as TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of undefined

Comment: 1st solution as TypeError: Cannot read property 'offset' of null

Comment: Is it scrolling to top when click? Is anything i have missed with this codesandbox code. IS nt moving for me.

Comment: Try again and let me know. Please treat it as  Pseudo-code that you can model your code against in React

Comment: yes.. its working.. I will surely check with this psudo code and once done will mark your answer as accepted. Many thanks for your time and effort.